# Firewalld: allow only certain source and destination port pairs

Tags: linux, firewall, port, firewalld

I am using [firewalld](https://firewalld.org/) to configure my firewall. I tried to create a service that allows a specific pair of source and destination ports:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="1234"/>
  <source-port protocol="tcp" port="4321"/>
</service>
```

I had expected that this would only allow clients communicating from port 4321 to connect to the server on port 1234. However, it seems that the service file just allows *both* all incoming connections to port 1234 and all connections coming from port 4321, if I understand the output from `nft list ruleset` correctly:

```bsh
…

chain filter_IN_public_allow {
        tcp dport 1234 ct state new,untracked accept
        tcp sport 4321 ct state new,untracked accept
}

…
```

So if this is not the proper approach. How can I achieve what I want with firewalld?

*(Edit: My further investigations lead me to believe that a so-called direct rule is necessary currently, i.e., essentially using iptables. I do not want that kind of solution…)*

Comment: rich-rule can fix this issue I think

Comment: I know this is old, but still current. How did you managed this?

Comment: @elysch: I did not.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `firewalld` is not designed that way. It doesn't contain an easy way to limit destinations. (If you consider rich rules not being an easy way :) )

The [RedHat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/pdf/configuring_firewalls_and_packet_filters/red_hat_enterprise_linux-9-configuring_firewalls_and_packet_filters-en-us.pdf) states (I added bold for emphasis):

> firewalld uses the concepts of zones and services, that simplify the
> traffic management. Zones are predefined sets of rules. Network
> interfaces and sources can be assigned to a zone. The traffic allowed
> depends on the network your computer is connected to and the security
> level this network is assigned. **Firewall services are predefined rules**
> that cover all necessary settings to allow ***incoming*** traffic for a
> specific service and they apply within a zone

The same documentation say, under title *1.1.1. When to use firewalld, nftables, or iptables*; that they recommend `firewalld` only for simple cases, and should use `nftables` to set up complex and performance-critical firewalls.

[Here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9/html/configuring_firewalls_and_packet_filters/getting-started-with-nftables_firewall-packet-filters) you can learn about nftables.

Article citation:

> **1.1. GETTING STARTED WITHFIREWALLD**
>
> The following is an introduction to firewalld features, such as services and zones, and how to manage the
> firewalld systemd service.
>
> **1.1.1. When to use firewalld, nftables, or iptables**
>
> The following is a brief overview in which scenario you should use one of the following utilities:
>
> **firewalld**: Use the **firewalld** utility for simple firewall use cases. The utility is easy to use and covers the typical use cases
> for these scenarios.
>
> **nftables**: Use the **nftables** utility to set up
> complex and performance-critical firewalls, such as for a whole
> network.
>
> **iptables**: The **iptables** utility on Red Hat Enterprise Linux
> uses the **nf_tables** kernel API instead of the legacy back end. The
> **nf_tables** API provides backward compatibility so that scripts that use **iptables** commands still work on Red Hat Enterprise Linux. For new firewall scripts, Red Hat recommends to use **nftables**.
>
> **IMPORTANT**
>
> To prevent the different firewall services from influencing each other, run only one of them on a RHEL host, and disable the other services.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Added the citation from the documentation provided by Red Hat